# Splitting string based on delimiter

Tags: java

A string is taken as input which is in the form of 23,4,555,67 via deadline nd another input is key yo search the element linearly ?my question is how can we recognize the elements from string separated by comma

Comment: Please tell us what's you sample input and output.

Comment: exactly what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the String using `split` :

```
String[] tokens = "23,4,555,67".split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "23,4,555,67"
String[] tokens = s.split(",");
```

This will give you a string array with the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a StringTokenizer. (java.util)

This can be used if your string is delimited by more than one characters (can be be used as well in case of single character). Your example using StringTokenizer

```
SrringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("23,4,555,67", ",");
while(st.hasMoreElements())
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```